# A one-way hash (no collisions) taking 32-bit integers to 36-bit integers?

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography

I want to use a one-way hashing algorithm (no collisions) to convert 32-bit integers to 36-bit integers.

Can anyone explain how to do that?

Comment: "One-way" and "no-collision" is difficult together. If it's hard enough to be considered "one-way", then it's probably too hard to prove that it's also collision-free.

Comment: Actually, with modern processors, it's not possible for this to be one-way. 32-bits can be easily brute-forced...

Comment: Are you implying that "one-way" and "no collision" are synonymous? They definitely are not. `h(x) = 0` is a one-way hash function.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP means "one-way" to be (impractical) to obtain `x` from `h(x)`.

Comment: Are you merely trying to make unique finger prints for 32-bit words, or are you actively trying to avoid preimage attacks?

Comment: I want to avoid pre-image atack.

Comment: `(long)x << 4` would work for the question, as stated

Comment: The identity function would also work.

Answer (score 8):

"One-way" means, that it is "hard" to figure out what x did give the hash-result h(x). Since the term "hard" is not sharply defined, there is also no sharp definition of what is a one-way function.

"No collision" means, that h(x) is different from h(y) for every pair of x and y where x is different from y. This is a sharp definition, but it is hard to prove if h(x) realy is a one-way-funcion. You must compare the hash-results of every pair of two 32-bit-numbers and test if they are different.

The best way to do this is to calculate all posible h(x) and store them, together with their x, in an array. Then sort the array by h(x), then walk through this list and test if two neighbours have the same h(x). If you don't find identic neighbours, your hash-function is free of collisions.

**BUT:** If you really can do this, your function can't really be a one-way-function, because the list you just generated to prove collision-freenes is a very fast lookup-table that lets you find the x for each h(x) in a searchtime of log(n). This might even be faster than calculation h(x) from x.

**So lets figure out, how long this really takes**

A 32-bit-integer is a number between 0 and 4294967295. Lets say it takes 0.1 ms to calculate h(x) from x. Depending on the hash-algorithm this is realistic even on a cheap notebook. So in 1 second you get 10,000 hash-numbers and in one day 864,000,000 numbers. It takes you just 5 days to calculate all posible numbers and to store them on disc.

Each entry has 4 byte for the 32-bit-number and 5 byte for the 36-bit-hash. Makes 9 byte. So the complete table has 38,654,705,664 byte. This is 38 GB. You can store this on every low-budged notebook. Sorting of this table needs some minutes, that doesn't count against the 5 days we needed for calculation.

So building this table on a second hand 200$-notebook is absolutely no problem. Once you have it, its very easy to prove if its really collision-free, but by building this table you did also prove that it is NOT a one-way function!

**So what is the best solution?**

1. Generate a list of 4,294,967,296 random 36-bit numbers, add to every entry a 32-bit-number that is the entries line-number (starting with 0).
2. Sort the list.
3. reset the did-change-a-number-flag
4. walk through the list. Compare the actual entry with the previous entry. If they are different, go to step 7.
5. replace the 36-bit-number by a new random 36-bit-number
6. set the did-change-a-number-flag
7. If you reached the end of the list: is the flag set? If so, go to step 2.
8. sort the list by the 32-bit-number (the previous line number)

After step 1 the list will contain 6,25% of collisions (about 268.4 million collisions). At each iteration you reduce the number of collisions to its 16th part. It will take aproximately 8 iterations to eliminate all collisons.

This 38 GB-Table is now you super-fast absolutely collision-free hash-function. And it is as one-way as any 32-to-36-bit-hashfunction can be. Meaning: There can be no other collision-free hash-function where it is harder to find x for a given h(x).

Comment: 0.1ms seems like a massive overestimation. There's also no need to store the 4 byte input number in your table - it's implied by its position in the table.

Comment: @NickJohnson: Storage of the 4 byte is needed to convert this table into a reverse lookup-table by sorting it by h(x).

Comment: Well, if you want a reverse lookup table, there are still more efficient ways to represent the data than duplicating the 36 bit and 32 bit identifiers for each key. For instance, you could build a trie based on the bits of the 36-bit hash.

Answer (score 3):

If 38 GB does not sound small to you, you could use the [Luby-Rackoff construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luby-Rackoff) with a 36-bit block.

First, pad your 32-bit input to 36 bits however you like.

Then generate a bunch of independent random keys `Ki`.  Make them as large as you want.  80-ish bits, say.  Store these `Ki` someplace safe, because you will be using them every time you "hash".

For the round function `F(Ki,x)`, use `SHA1(Ki . x)` truncated to 18 bits.

Four rounds of this should do nicely.  And it is certainly one-to-one because it is actually invertible if you have the `Ki`.

(Yeah yeah, "never invent your own cryptography".  But with only 32 bits of input, who cares?)